# Drupal 7 inject div into existing structure

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am using drupal 7

views-view--myview.tpl.php sample code
`<?php if ($rows): ?>

<?php print $rows; ?>`

When i see this in firebug i see the structure
`<div class="item-list">

<ul>

<li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">  </li>

<li class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even "> </li>`

Now how do i inject a div in each of these li.. Is this possible without using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

If you go the the "Edit" page for the view, you should see a link called "**Theme: Information**". It's under the "**Style Settings**" section.  If you click this, you can see a list of all the possible template that your theme will look for when displaying the view.  In bold will be the file it is currently using.

views-view--myview.tpl.php is to high up the chain to do what you want.  If you want to inject a div (the same div) around each field you output, then I think the file **views-view-field.tpl.php** is what you are looking for.

The file contains just the line

```
<?php print $output; ?>
```

So there you can insert the desired div (after you copy it from views/themes into the template directory for your theme, of course).

If you investigate the **Theme Information** link some more it describes how to be even more specific in naming the view template files, for example if you wanted to theme a specific row differently you could use the file **views-view-field--entity-id-X**.

Hope that helps!

EDIT for comment

To go a different route, you can also edit the field settings for your view.  Under the **Field** tab on the edit view page, you can click the links for each field.  There is a **Suffix** setting available you could use to inject a div after the field is displayed.

Comment: @Andy sure thing, let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Now i have created a file with name views-view-field--test-item-caption.tpl.php (this was suggested in theme information) .  A div by this field name already exists in each of my li's. Now how do i modify this new file to append new div to this existing one..